# search through a range of directories bash script

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, scripting

I have written (tried to) this small bash script for searching through a range of directories.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for file in [ac]*/blarg
do 
   echo $file
   done
```

This script searches through directories starting with "a" through "c" for "blarg".
It only goes one level deep. How can I make it step through all directories it might encounter, and not just the root of the directories with the starting letter.

Also, is this question supposed to go here at stackoverflow or would superuser be more suitable?

Thanks

Comment: If you actually mean ‘a’ through ‘c’, your pattern needs to be **[a-c]**, not just **[ac]**.

Comment: Note: Answers given by benjamin button and 1ch1g0 are both correct and do what I need. But because I can only accept one answer, I had to pick benjamin button since he was first.
Sorry 1ch1g0 (I did mod your answer up though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the command line ths will do your purpose.so why to go for a script?

```
find ./[ac]*/ -name "blarg"
```

if you still need a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglobi
for file in `find ./[ac]*/ -name "blarg"`
do
echo $file
done
```

Comment: It should be `./[ac]*/`. It also fails if filenames have spaces. It should be `find... | while read file...` or `while read file...done < <(find ...)`

Comment: Closer, but using `read` will still fail with pathnames with newlines in them. `find [ac]*/ -name blarg -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'for file in "$@"; do …; done'`

Comment: @Chris/Dennnis: `while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do...done < <(find ... -print0)`  That will handle any file name you can throw at it. No need for xargs.

Answer (score 3):

if you have Bash 4.0 you can try globstar

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s globstar
for file in [ac]*/**/blarg
do 
   echo $file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo `find blarg`
```

Replace that line and you'll find all files under [ac]* named blarg.